# WorksheetFunction.Month error with object doesn't support property or method

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to save a file into folder & sub folder that has dynamic names.

Structure of my folder & sub folder is

> Shared Drive -> Main -> Year (i.e. 2018) -> Month (i.e. 09 September).

I wish to save in last month's folder since data comes from last month. I want to save the file name as PIF_09.30.2018 so using end of last month's dates.

I am getting an error

> object doesn't support this property or method.

```vb
Sub Save_wkb()
Dim Path As String
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "S:\Main\" & Format(Now(), "YYYY") & _
     Application.PathSeparator & Format(WorksheetFunction.Month(Now, -1), "MM ") & _
   Format(WorksheetFunction.Month(Now, -1), "MMMM") & _
   Application.PathSeparator & "PIF_" & _
   Format(WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Now, -1), "MM.D.YYYY") & ".xlsx", _
   FileFormat:=51
End Sub
```

Comment: `WorksheetFunction.Month(Now, -1)` is the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not able to use `WorksheetFunction.Month` - it doesn't exist.

Since you are trying to subtract a month, you can use the `DateAdd()` function instead.

```
Dim Path As String
Path = "S:\Main\" & Format(Now(), "YYYY") & Application.PathSeparator & _
    Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "00 ") & Application.PathSeparator & _
    Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "MMMM") & Application.PathSeparator & _
    "PIF_" & Format(WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Now, -1), "M.D.YYYY") & ".xlsx"
```

Comment: Thank you, I learned something today...to use `Dateadd()`. Your codes just needs slightly changed since 09 September is the folder name, but I was able to get it to work, just take out second `Application.PathSeparator`.